# date picker is not hiding after selecting date. I want to hide calendar after selecting date and at the same time i want to call a function

Tags: jquery, datepicker

date picker is not hiding after selecting date. I want to hide calandar after selecting date and at the same time i want to call a function.

I am calling function at the time of selecting date, because onchange event is not raising after changing the text box value to new date.

I have written code like this,

```
$('input:text[id^=ExpireDate]').datepicker({
    //-
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(this).val(dateText);
        fun2(id, expireDate);
    }
});

fun2(id, date) {
    //--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to hide the element is

```
$(this).hide();
```

Comment: This is actually better asked as comment to the OP's question since this does not directly states the answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer.  As the user does not directly ask the question, this level of subtlety is correct in my culture.